# Is there a way to auto update dates in script to the last months first and last day?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to have these two dates change at the start of every month to the 1st and last day of the month before.

I have the desired dates updating in the sheet but can't use those cells as references.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
  var mycal = "oli@waggerspack.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

  var events = cal.getEvents(
      new Date("1 September, 2018 00:00:00 GMT"), // this date
      new Date("30 September, 2018 23:59:59 GMT"), // and this one
      {search: 'Keba & Jenga'});

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var header = [["Invoice"]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1);
  range.setValues(header);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var row = i + 12;
    var myformula_placeholder = '';

    var details = [[events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime()]];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
    range.setValues(details);

    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 3);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' + row + ')+(MINUTE(F' + row + ')/60))-(HOUR(E' + row + ')+(MINUTE(E' + row + ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to use your server local time:

```js
var today=new Date();
var startDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-1, 1, 0,0,0); 
var endDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1, 0,0,0); 
endDate.setSeconds(-1);

document.write(startDate);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(endDate);
```

If you prefer to always use GMT+0 time than you have to use this code:

```js
var today=new Date();
today=new Date(today.valueOf() +  today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var startDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-1, 1, 0,0,0); 
var endDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1, 0,0,0); 
endDate.setSeconds(-1);
console.log(today);
console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);
```

your code will be like this (for local time):

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
  var mycal = "oli@waggerspack.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

var today=new Date();
var startDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-1, 1, 0,0,0); 
var endDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1, 0,0,0); 
endDate.setSeconds(-1);

  var events = cal.getEvents(
      startDate, // this date
      endDate, // and this one
      {search: 'Keba & Jenga'});

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var header = [["Invoice"]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1);
  range.setValues(header);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var row = i + 12;
    var myformula_placeholder = '';

    var details = [[events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime()]];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
    range.setValues(details);

    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 3);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' + row + ')+(MINUTE(F' + row + ')/60))-(HOUR(E' + row + ')+(MINUTE(E' + row + ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('');
  }
}
```

or your code might be like this (for GMT+0 time):

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
  var mycal = "oli@waggerspack.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

 var today=new Date();
today=new Date(today.valueOf() +  today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var startDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-1, 1, 0,0,0); 
var endDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1, 0,0,0); 
endDate.setSeconds(-1);


  var events = cal.getEvents(
      startDate, // this date
      endDate, // and this one
      {search: 'Keba & Jenga'});

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var header = [["Invoice"]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1);
  range.setValues(header);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var row = i + 12;
    var myformula_placeholder = '';

    var details = [[events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime()]];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
    range.setValues(details);

    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 3);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' + row + ')+(MINUTE(F' + row + ')/60))-(HOUR(E' + row + ')+(MINUTE(E' + row + ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I used a similar script in the end.

I took the first date of the current month -23 minutes to stop me getting events from the current month. Seems to work well. Will post when done